# Increase/Decrease Brightness F-keys on Keyboard not working in AlmaLinux?

Tags: centos, gnome, desktop-environment, wayland, backlight

After installing AlmaLinux on a Toshiba Portege laptop and choosing the workstation setup, the brightness control keys do not work.

The hardware is capable and Linux compatible, as evidenced by the fact that a dual boot of Linux Mint has no issue with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these instructions:

1. Run `sudo gedit /opt/brightctl` and copy and paste in the following text:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   INCREMENT=50
   MINIMUM=1
   MAXIMUM=$(</sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness)

   brightness=$(</sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)

   let brightness/=$INCREMENT
   let brightness*=$INCREMENT

   if test "_$1" = "_--brighter" ; then
     let brightness+=$INCREMENT
   fi

   if test "_$1" = "_--dimmer" ; then
     let brightness-=$INCREMENT
   fi

   if test $brightness -lt $MINIMUM ; then
     brightness=$MINIMUM
   fi

   if test $brightness -gt $MAXIMUM ; then
     brightness=$MAXIMUM
   fi

   echo $brightness > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
   ```

   [image: Create the brightctl script file]
2. Make the script executable with `sudo chmod +x /opt/brightctl`

   [image: Make the brightctl script exectuable]
3. Run `sudo gedit /etc/sudoers` and add the following two lines:

   ```
   ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/brightctl --brighter
   ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/brightctl --dimmer
   ```

   [image: Append these lines to the sudoers file]
4. Search in the start menu for *keyboard* and open the Keyboard settings.

   [image: Start-menu search for keyboard system settings]
5. Add keyboard binding for brightness increase command (`sudo /opt/brightctl --brighter`) and bind it to your brightness key on your keyboard

   [image: Set Custom Shortcut for brighten]
6. Add keyboard binding for brightness decrease command (`sudo /opt/brightctl --dimmer`) and bind it to your brightness key on your keyboard

   [image: Set Custom Shortcut for dimmer]
7. Try using your brightness keys now. It should work immediately without reboot or anything.